# Sample JSON request for multipart form

Tags: json, api, rest, multipartform-data, multipart

I want to call a rest API and my request body is composed in a json file. I want to send the request as multipart/form. Request body containst some text fields and several files for which I decide to use multipart form. I have found alot of logical example requests on internet but no concrete example in json format.

How would a sample json request body look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally found out that there is no such JSON representation of multipart/data requests. Infect thats just not possible using the json format. So multipart data request literally looks like the attached screenshot:

[image]